# How to check if ID in database exists

Tags: php, mysql, get

Why won't this send the user to user.php if the ID don't exist in the table?

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$id_exists = false;
$url_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE id='$url_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
 
if ($result == $url_id)
{
        $id_exists = true;
}
 
else if ($result != $url_id)
{
        $id_exists = false;
        header("location:user.php");
        exit();
}
 
?>
```

Comment: What one would usually do is use debugging to find out. Also check out the manual for what values `mysql_query()` returns

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$url_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE id='$url_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0){
   //found
}else{
   //not found
}
```

Try something like this :).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look the num-rows function too.

Answer (score 2):

Please, read the docs for [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query). You have to fetch the result after making the query. That said, you should probably use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) instead of `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 0):

Because mysql_query doesn't return a row, it returns a resource.

Use `mysql_num_rows($result)` to check if there is a row returned.

Comment: For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

Comment: @Pramendra: A query that returns zero rows is still successful, therefore a resource will be returned with no rows, not FALSE.